# Using ImageSharp to adjust levels and colors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, imagesharp

```
myImage.Mutate(i => i.Saturate(2).Resize(new ResizeOptions { Mode = ResizeMode.Crop, Position = AnchorPositionMode.Center, Size = new Size(width, height) }));
```

I am trying to convert a Photoshop job to be done by ImageSharp in my .NET Core application - most of it goes well, see example above, but I miss 2 things;

How do I adjust Levels (like Image -> Adjustment -> Levels in Photoshop)?

How do I change number of colors used, want to go to e.g. 20 colors (like Image -> Mode -> Index Color in Photoshop)?

I need it to be done between Saturate and Resize if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the image -> Adjustment -> Levels you can check this project for example: [Image Magic - Image Levels using Custom Controls](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83953/Image-Magic-Image-Levels-using-Custom-Controls)

Comment: I would prefer not to mix too much with ImageSharp - but even though it is not perfect I got pretty close using Contrast, Quantize and ending with Pixelate.